# How to add value indicators (circle dots) in Radar chart Data sets using MpAndoidChart Lib?

Tags: mpandroidchart, radar-chart

[LineDataSet](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet.html) class contains API [setCircleRadius()](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet.html#setCircleRadius-float-) but I need similar functionality in [RadarDataSet](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/RadarDataSet.html) class. Can some one help ?

[image: small circle dots]